# No log files are being created using winston node js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, npm, winston

I am working in node js and using Winston library for logging. The following code does not create a log file.

```
var winston = require('winston');


var logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
            level: 'info',
            filename: './logs/all-logs.log',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: true,
            maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
            maxFiles: 5,
            colorize: false
        }),
        new winston.transports.Console({
            level: 'debug',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: false,
            colorize: true
        })
    ],
    exitOnError: false
});

module.exports = logger;
module.exports.stream = {
    write: function(message, encoding){
        logger.info(message);
    }
};
```

logger.info("hello world");

It logs to the terminal fine:

```
 {"message":"hello world","level":"info"}
```

Directory Structure is like this

```
-test.js
-winston.js
-log
```

Comment: Good question!! +1,for that, check my answer below.

Comment: I have updated the answer with some final changes can you retry all the steps from answer. MOST IMP **do the npm install of required packages.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's you should use Winston:

*Below code creates log files in `/log/` directory.*

---

### First, install the **winston-daily-rotate-file, fs, and winston** using:

```
npm i winston-daily-rotate-file fs winston
```

Create a file with name **winston.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const winston = require("winston");
const logDir = "log";

if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
}

const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
module.exports = logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.colorize(),
                winston.format.timestamp(),
                winston.format.align(),
                winston.format.simple(),
            ),
            level: 'info'
        }),
        new (require("winston-daily-rotate-file"))({
            filename: `${logDir}/-results.log`,
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.timestamp(),
                winston.format.json(),
            )
        }),
        new winston.transports.File({ 
            filename: 'log/error.log', 
            level: 'error',
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.timestamp(),
                winston.format.simple(),
            )
        }),
    ]
});
```

---

### Now all you have to do is, import the logger and use it. Below is the example.

Now in the same directory, create a new file **test.js** and add following code:

```
const logger = require("./winston.js");

logger.info(`Test info Log!`);
logger.error(`Test error Log!`);
```

---

Now run test.js using

```
node test.js
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: This code should create `/log/` directory in the project folder. Can you check you root directory of the project.

Comment: btw how to call this function. I mean I have wrote all your code in one file and run it through console. nothing prints out and I don't see any file as well in the log directory

Comment: Check the answer now. And if the log directory is created this means the above code is working, you just need to use it properly.

Comment: Actually I have created manually the log directory. okay I am going to try your code

Comment: still no log.. no error file has been generating in my log directory. but result is printing out on console successfully

Comment: Can you post your directory structure? in your question

Comment: sure. I'll do it

Comment: I am not sure, what wrong you are doing here, but the code i just posted. I tried it again and it is working fine now as well.

Comment: did you install `winston-daily-rotate-file`?? use `npm i winston-daily-rotate-file` and try again.

Comment: We are loggin the error level logs in the error file let me update my question once.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. Thank you for your time

Comment: Great!! It wasn't working as we were logging the errors in **info** level and were checking the logs for **error** level.

Comment: Okay I have one more question if you can help me.. I want to create multiple log files. I mean I need a functionality something like I do this 
logger.info(`Test info Log!`,'filename'); and it logs everything in that file. is it possible?

Comment: We can do that, I would suggest you create another question for it. So that I could answer there, relevantly.

Comment: I have updated your answer. here is another question I posted 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547294/how-to-create-multiple-log-files-and-append-logs-in-that-file-using-winston-libr

Comment: Okay give me a moment,

Comment: Could you help answer this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985123/error-logs-are-not-passed-to-the-error-log-file-when-debug-logs-does-why-does-t related to winston?