# How to create multiple log files and append logs in that file using winston library

Tags: node.js, winston

I am using Winston library in nodes for error logs. Now what I want is to create multiple logger files dynamically.

The code I am using is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51546275/1495272)

```
const fs = require("fs");
const winston = require("winston");
const logDir = "log";

if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
}

const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
module.exports = logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.colorize(),
                winston.format.timestamp(),
                winston.format.align(),
                winston.format.simple(),
            ),
            level: 'info'
        }),
        new (require("winston-daily-rotate-file"))({
            filename: `${logDir}/-results.log`,
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.timestamp(),
                winston.format.json(),
            )
        }),
        new winston.transports.File({ 
            filename: 'log/error.log', 
            level: 'error',
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.timestamp(),
                winston.format.simple(),
            )
        }),
    ]
});
```

I need something like if I pass a filename calling logger

```
logger.info(`Test info Log!`,'filename');
```

It should log file in this filename. if file doesn't exist it creates it and  appends everything in that file

Comment: create multiple loggers: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#working-with-multiple-loggers-in-winston

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve here is creating the log files dynamically by specifying the filename.

Which is **Not Possible** as we have to declare the files and logger options while we instantiate the logger instance in the winston.js file.

Here:

```
module.exports = logger = winston.createLogger({}
```

And you cannot update it on the go!

Hope I have cleared your thoughts!