# Error logs are not passed to the error log file when debug logs does. Why does that happen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, es6-class, winston

I am trying to create a simple logger class with [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston). I created two loggers named `Logger` and `Error` which extends from `Logger`.

The `Logger` class by default creates all the logs in `al-logs.log` and `Error` class when extending from `Logger` adds an additional transport to create all `error` logs inside `error-logs.log`. But no logs are created inside `error-logs.log`. What am I missing?

Here is what I did:

First, I created the `Logger` class:

```
  class Logger {
    constructor(serviceName, label = "") {
        this.logger = winston.createLogger({
            level: "debug",
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.label({ label }),
                winston.format.timestamp(),
                winston.format.json()
            ),
            defaultMeta: {
                service: serviceName
            },
            transports: [
                new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'all-logs.log' })
            ],
            exceptionHandlers: [
                new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'exceptions.log' })
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

Then I created a class named `Error` that extends the above `Logger` class:

```
class Error extends Logger {
    constructor(serviceName, label = "") {
        super(serviceName, label);
        this.logger.level = "error";
        this.logger.transports.push(new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error-logs.log', level: this.logger.level }))
    }
}
```

Then I created a method named `console.error`:

```
const errorLogger = new Error("test-service");


console.error = (...args) => {
    errorLogger.logger.error(args.join(" "))
}
```

Now, if I do:

```
console.error("some error")
```

it does not get logged to the `error-logs.log` file but just gets logged to the `all-logs.log` from the `Logger` class. Why does not anything gets logged to the `error-logs.log` file?